# C#, Access, Query For T/F Condition & Retrieve Other Column String

Tags: c#, ms-access

Evening,

I am attempting to loop through a List which hold a list of brand names. In each iteration it calls the query. The Query is attempting to check if the given column, which is named after the brand name, is true. In which case, add the Model string value of the first column.

The closest I've been able to get is it'll iterate through all the brands correctly, but adds all models to each brand. This makes sense as all models, technically, have a 'true' for that brand, however I do not know of a clean, simple way to filter it.

I've done a test method where instead of iterating the Parameter value from the brand list I hard-coded it into the query, the query works as intended thus stumping me as to why it is not working. The parameter value is correctly changing with each iteration.

```
private static void SetAPDictionary()
    {
        if (AP_BRAND_DICTIONARY == null)
        {
            AP_BRAND_DICTIONARY = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

            // For each Brand added into the Brand Catalog, iterate through and query for each brand and allocate accordingly into the Dictionary. 
            foreach (string brand in Root_Toolbox.BrandCatalog)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NOW QUERYING FOR "+ brand);
                //DemoCode(brand);
                APQueryCaller(brand);
            }
        }
    }

    // TEST CODE; WORKS AS DESIRED.
    private static void DemoCode(string brand)
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT [Model] FROM [Copy of AP_Brand] WHERE @p1 = -1", Connection_Controller.MasterDbConnection(true)))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", brand);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DEMO ADDING " + reader.GetString(0) + " TO " + brand);
            }
        }
        Connection_Controller.MasterDbConnection(false);
    }
    // END TEST

    // TODO: FIX ME... 
    public static void APQueryCaller(string brand)
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT [Model] FROM [AP_Brand] WHERE @p1 = YES", Connection_Controller.MasterDbConnection(true)))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", brand);

            // DEBUG 
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText);
            foreach (OleDbParameter i in cmd.Parameters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("@p1 IS NOW: " + i.Value);
            }
            // END DEBUG


            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (!AP_BRAND_DICTIONARY.ContainsKey(brand))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ADDING " + brand);
                AP_BRAND_DICTIONARY.Add(brand, new List<string>());
            }

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // If the column with the brand name is checked (true) add to the dictionary. 

            }
        }
        Connection_Controller.MasterDbConnection(false);
    }
```

As for the database layout. MDU should be the only brand to get the models in its list.

[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKHC8.png)

Comment: Did you mean `WHERE @p1 = 'YES'` ? (with single quotes) Also you generally filter on the column, not the parameter value that you pass in, similar to `WHERE [table].[column] = @p1`

Answer (score 1):

Like Igor pointed out in his comment... you are not using the column name in your where clause.  I can't comment (not enough reputation yet).

The way this looks to me: brand is a string value?  For example: "MDU"

Here is what you have now:

```
  SELECT [Model] FROM [AP_Brand] WHERE @p1 = YES
  --Are you expecting this to turn into
  SELECT [Model] FROM [AP_Brand] WHERE MDU = YES
```

My suggestion:

```
@"SELECT [Model] FROM [AP_Brand] WHERE " + brand + " = @p1";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", -1);
```

This now outputs:

```
SELECT [Model] FROM [AP_Brand] WHERE MDU = -1
```

**Note:** *concatenating the string above is open for SQL injection, make sure to scrub the brand variable before building your SQL statement.*

Comment: Didn't realize this question was from 2018... gotta build those reputation points somehow! :)

Comment: Good luck with that Pete...be patient with the culture...there's a learning curve.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani: the time and effort might not be in vain if someone comes along and finds it useful.

Comment: I was really referring to building the reputation points...But as for the late answer...Its really never too late to answer. SO is like a big reference guide. There are plenty of times where I research question and come back and put in another answer.